# Filtering empty rows from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to form an SQL query to retrieve some records, however the issue I am having is that my query retrieving empty rows.

The query below retrieves the following rows, however I need the last few rows not to appear. I tried adding `AND vanDeduction != ''` to the end of this query, but this makes it miss important data.

```
SELECT rnumber,date,grossInvoice,sTaxFee1Charged,vanDeduction 
FROM ledger 
where rnumber = 'R-022074'
```

[image: SQL Response]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: in your logic what does " empty rows" mean?

Comment: `DriverPayment` is not in the query, but it is in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT rnumber, date, grossInvoice, sTaxFee1Charged, vanDeduction 
FROM ledger 
WHERE rnumber = 'R-022074' AND
      (grossInvoice > 0 or sTaxFee1Charged > 0 or driverPayment > 0);
```